# why child process not support query session

Tags: node.js

hello guys I search a lot on the internet as well as I tried the below thing but this does not work I don't know why

```
 const exec = require('child_process');
 let p = exec.execSync("query session").toString();
```

can anyone tell me why the above line "query session" is not working other than this eg "tasklist","whoami" etc everything working fine

error throw like show below:

```
   Error: Command failed:  query session rpa-agent1
     at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
     at Object.execSync (child_process.js:666:13)
     at TestScreen.execute (C:\Users\Public\production_rpa_agent\action- 
     paths\testscreen\index.js:39:21)
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Public\production_rpa_agent\action-paths\testscreen\index.js:67:4)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
```

query session is a window command used for getting rdp login user.

Comment: What is `query session`? Windows specific?

Comment: Also, how exactly is it _not working_?

Comment: @tadman updated my question, yes it window specific and this working If i directly typed in cmd

Comment: @bereal update my question

Comment: I usually split arguments from commands, so `"query", "session"`, as this might be looking for `"query session.exe"` literally.

Comment: @tadman it "query session" not "query session.exe" this will work in server (was or other cloud)

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I'm saying you may need to split the arguments from the command itself.

Comment: @tadman can you give a sample code?

Comment: I literally just did. Separate them. Like I just showed.

Comment: @tadman , i tried  this exec.execSync(" QUERY","SESSION").toString(); but still it throw error like Invalid parameter(s)
QUERY { PROCESS | SESSION | TERMSERVER | USER }